# Help with truth table and K-Maps

Tags: circuit-design, truth-table

I am currently working on a traffic light system, the state transition table developed for the project reads as follows:
[image]
I have additionally used Neeman's Digital software to create a table (and K-Maps) for the output F2, F1, and F0.

As I was trying to repeat the process for D2, D1 and D0, with a table that has the following appearance. I would like to clarify that the Input I is being represented by E in the table.
[image: D truth table]

Which returns the following expressions for the output expressions:
[image: x expressions]

I have also tried replacing the x with 0 and get the following output expressions:
[image: 0 expressions]

Both these aproaches revealed insufficient, because only F0 (the GREEN light) gets lit up, even when Input is true.
I would therefore like help resolving this issue.
Thank you very much.

Comment: What is clocking the flip flops?  What is stopping you from using a counter?  Or a microprocessor?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE/EE! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". This is not a forum.

Comment: Basically you can use a synchronous counter with synchronous reset and some combinatorial logic. You can even build the counter from 3 D flip flops (as you correctly assume) and some combinatorial logic. -- Using a K-map is perfectly fine, and you might want to do some research on finite state machines. -- `I` and `Sn` are your inputs, `Sn+1` (= `D`) and `F` your outputs.  -- Now start and if you stumble with a specific issue, [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Nobody does stuff like this in discreet logic any longer. Any tired old MCU will moonwalk past all your Karnaugh maps and flip flops. It's some 15 mins of work to hack down if you know C programming.

Comment: @vir i was specifically tasked to implement this without counters, for i had an implementation with them prior to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### to start

I believe you have correctly drawn out a viable table with everything you need. I can't argue with it. But it appears you need help with k-maps. So let's get going on that.

*(In the following, I'm using a tool called [**Neemann's Digital**](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital).)*

#### RED k-map

The k-map for the RED LIGHT is probably easier to see and make from your table:

\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\$ [image]

Here's what the above might look like as a start for your circuit:

[image]

#### GREEN k-map

The k-map for the GREEN LIGHT is only slightly harder to see by eye:

\$\quad\quad\quad\quad\$ [image]

But you know that it must only the case for \$\overline{S_2}\: \overline{S_1}\: \overline{S_0}\$, too, because of how you designed things. So it's not difficult to work out the above k-map from that knowledge.

Here's the newly modified circuit to include that light:

[image]

#### RED k-map you produced

But let's stop for a moment and look at what you ***actually*** produced for your **RED** table (newly updated in your question -- thanks):

[image]

It's not correct. I'm not sure how you created your table on the left side there. But you missed a lot. Do you see how it is really just \$S_2+S_1 S_0\$?

*(This is just doing it **by eye**. But it's also not hard to see.)*

#### automated tool

Perhaps you would like to use an automated tool for this work, instead?

Let's take a moment's break and grab up a copy of [**Neemann's Digital**](https://github.com/hneemann/Digital).

Then you may access the following service it offers:

[image]

This will pop up a starter dialog for you that looks like this:

[image]

Right-click on the titles to change them *(note that using an underscore in the name causes the following text to appear as a subscript)*:

[image]

Then add another input variable:

[image]

Unfortunately, this adds it to the end of the current list *(and gives it a default name, which you need to rename as well.)* So move it to the front:

[image]

Now rename the output column **Y** to **RED** and add more output columns:

[image]

Your table might now look like this:

[image]

At this point, start marking the values in the output columns. For example, this is what it looks like when modifying the **GREEN** column to make it a **1**:

[image]

When done, you should have the following table completed:

[image]

Then select the k-map option:

[image]

Then you can work through that to find:

[image]

This is a little more nuanced than what I produced above, as it includes the `don't care` states for **state 7**.

If you now use the following table service:

[image]

It will generate the logic for the above in a separate instance of **Digital**:

[image]

On the left side above is what **Digital** generated, directly, using **AND**/**OR** logic.

Clearly, also, the inputs will instead be coming from the D FFs you already know you need to set up. So on the right side I've added those, by hand.

### summary

At this point, I think I've carried you far enough along. You should be able to generate your own table for creating the inputs needed for the D FFs. If you followed the above process, all you need to do is now add three more output columns to represent the next state in your table. Then correctly fill them out. (*If you want, you can reorder the output columns, too.*)

I also would suggest that you play with some of the other options you have available in **Digital**, too. I've only touched upon a few of your choices. For example, **Digital** will generate CUPL or JEDEC code that can be used to program a [GAL16V8](https://ece-classes.usc.edu/ee459/library/datasheets/16v8.pdf)! Explore.

Comment: I provided context and the current KMaps I have, I had to put them into excel and took me longer to do so, I apologize. @periblepsis

Comment: I would create a synchronous sequential network by configuring the flip flops in toggle mode. Then I would determine the logical networks for the individual traffic lights by considering the transition table of the Q outputs or even the D inputs and the I switch.

Comment: @ramwen0 You may want to capture the information here and include it into your first question, as clarifying it. I can either add another answer there or else edit my existing answer. Or I can just edit here. Either way, it seems you may need help with k-maps.

Comment: @ramwen0 In your newly added tables for RED, GREEN, and YELLOW, is **E** the same as you earlier wrote as **I**?

Comment: @periblepsis it indeed is, I apologize for the lack of consistency in naming conventions.

Comment: @ramwen0 Hopefully, the above helps you move along. If you run into more troubles, I think it would be acceptable for you to ask another question that is specific to the issue stopping you. (It won't be the same question, anymore.)

Comment: thank you for the extensive help on this matter as well, i really appreciate it.

Comment: @ramwen0 I want you to learn and succeed well. Best wishes. (It's up to you whether or not you select my answer. I don't care either way. It's just bookkeeping.)

Comment: Thank you for your patience, however I have one question, what's happened to my I input? how shall the inputs of the D FFs know its active (or not) in order to trigger them as well? I'm asking this while implementing the logic, right after repeating the process you've gracefully documented above, for the D FFs.

Comment: @ramwen0 I didn't include that part of your table in my work, choosing instead to leave it for you to add on your own. It's not hard to do. Just apply yourself to the table and add the columns, then fill out the details you already know about in your table. Then hook things up to the D FF inputs.

Comment: I understand, however I seem to be stuck, for the K-Map solver gives out S_2, S_1 and S_0 as the input, which doesn't compute well. Additionally, if I instead of x place a 0 in 1,1,1 I get a different expression, however the same result, in which only F0 lights up, not performing thr cycle I'd like it to...

Comment: @ramwen0 Since you had problems earlier, you will need to edit your question and include images of the table you developed and your work product. Otherwise, I'm just guessing. My work runs just fine here. So I know that the above process I illustrated works perfectly, when used and applied correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Comment: I have altered the questoin. I hope I have provided enough context @periblepsis

Comment: @ramwen0 That table has ***serious*** problems!!

Comment: wait is it because the output is basically the same as the input??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151073/discussion-between-ramwen0-and-periblepsis).